# Faire un/des effort/s

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

I'm wondering if the expressions "faire un effort" and "faire des efforts" are interchangeable? Would it for example be possible to say both:

> Il essaye vraiment de faire un effort pour continuer avec sa vie comme avant

> Il essaye vraiment de faire des efforts pour continuer avec sa vie comme avant

Comment: Je dirais qu'on utilise 'fais un effort' pour quelque chose qui se fait dans l'instant alors que 'fais des efforts' est plutôt dans la durée

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @vc-74 said in the comments, "faire un effort" would be used in the action/moment while "faire des efforts" would be used to describe efforts in a mid/long term situation.

The more correct phrasing in your example would be

> Il essaye vraiment de faire des efforts pour continuer avec sa vie comme avant

The first one would imply that going on with his life (after a break-up, the death of a loved one, etc.) is a one-shot effort, which is almost never the case.

Also, "fais un effort" can be and is more often used in a joking/mocking manner

> "- Tu peux m'aider à ouvrir cette bouteille d'eau ?"
>
> "- Oh, fais un effort !"